# Plots of data using DBSCAN algorithm not making sense

Tags: clustering, visualization, machine-learning-model, plotting, dbscan

I am using clustering for my data. Since the DBSCAN algorithm will also tell me an estimate of clusters that I can use, I have used DBSCAN. I have tried for the `eps=[0.123,1,2]` and `min_smaples=[2,10,...60]`. The print satatement in the below code prints 714 which is equal to the number of data-samples(rows). The code looks like:

```
dbscan = DBSCAN(eps=1, min_samples = 4)
clusters = dbscan.fit_predict(df)
print(len(clusters))
plt.scatter(df.iloc[:, 0], df.iloc[:, 1], c=clusters, cmap="plasma")
plt.xlabel("Feature 0")
plt.ylabel("Feature 1")
```

Sample plots for some of the different `min_samples` is shown below:

[image: EPS=1, MIN_SAMPLES=2]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The parameters for the above plots are given below in the same pattern.

1. EPS=1, MIN_SAMPLES=2, EPS=1, MIN_SAMPLES=10
2. EPS=1, MIN_SAMPLES=20, EPS=1, MIN_SAMPLES=40

None of these plots are making sense to me from a clustering perspective. From this, I am forced to conclude that I cannot use clustering for the given data or I am doing it wrong. So, I need help with insights into the weird appearance of the above plots.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

**Dont try to visually confirm it.**

You are plotting your clustering resutls in ONLY two dimensions and you expect that all of the information is in these two dimesnions. That is very unlikely. If you plot 3 dimensions you will see even  more seperability and it will make a bit more sense. In any case you need a metric for example [Silhouette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_(clustering)) that tells you how well you clustered. Visualisation is just a sanity check if you know your features already.

Comment: The silhouette score was -0.19. I have used OPTICS also and there is no improvement. So, do I conclude that the data is so close that the model is not able to separate them? K-means also gave a score of 0.17.

Comment: Well at the moment, there is all sorts of pre-processing, agumentations and transformations that you can use

Comment: Silhouette does not work for non-convex clusters, and does not handle noise well, hence it is not a good measure to use with DBSCAN.

Comment: Can you send me a reference please regarding non-convex

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to find parameters by brute force.

Instead, analyze your data. The choice of minpts is application driven - how noisy your data is, how many points you require for a point to be considered important. Based on this, you can choose epsilon based on the k-distance plot.

Try projecting your data into different views when you have multiple dimensions.

Also try different preprocessing. You seem to have scaled your data to 0:1, but is this the right scaling to capture similarity? If your distance does not capture similarity, then DBSCAN will not work because it relies on your distance function...